# getting ElementClickInterceptedException in the firefox browser

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

```java
public void clickRecentRuns() {
           
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser.getDriver(), 60);
       
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeContains(By.xpath("//h4[@class='media-box-heading ng-binding']"), "class", "media-box-heading ng-binding"));

       WebElement recentRunsButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(homePagePropertyParser
               .getPropertyValue(FilePathConstants.FALCON_LOCATOR_FILE_PATH, LocatorKeyContainer.RECENT_RUNS_BUTTON))));
       recentRunsButton.click();
}
```

This is my method to click one button on the sidebar which is recentrun button in the home page. I have tried using all the wait conditions to click the recent run button after the page loaded but the application is not responding for those wait commands and directly clicking the button before the UI loads and i am getting landed on the recents run page. atlast i got this attributecontains solution to wait for the UI loaded and click the recents button the home page. this code is working fine in the chrome and egde browser but while i am running in the firefox browser i am facing Element Click Intercepted Exception error.

Note : I have used javascript executor method to click as well but it is directly landing in the recent run page. I need to land on home page first and then click the element.

I have tried almost all the wait conditions but it is not responding and i should not use Thread.sleep

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the element you want to click has an overlay which is visible or invisible. The overlay would be stacked on top of other elements by the app developers. To click the button find the overlay and click at the location of the button. Note: Sometimes the overlay might just be the element above the element you want to interact with. If that is the case simply use that element XPath to click.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I tried that as well. there is no overlay for that element

Comment: @vivek.raji You will have to try other elements in the tree it could be any element(don't look just for an overlay). I bet the answer lies in the page source only